# Access UI chart text legend sorted as number

Tags: ms-access, user-interface

I have searched for a solution but I can't find one suitable on this problem.

I have a chart in access where the Y-axis is text but starts with a number, so up along the y-axis i get this:

[image: Chart with incorrect order on Y-axis]

[image: Table data for chart]

I know why, but I don't know how to fix it.
They all have an ID which is fine. I can chose to put the ID on the Y-axis, but then the kW range can't be visualized.

How is this changed?

Changing the text to number is not possible as it needs to be like "a-b kW".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could add 0 so it was 050-075 and so on but that looks like a bugger.

Comment: Really, Access's charting functions are sub-par.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who might get this problem, I found out why.

When selecting the data, it chose to use the "Total" function, and "Avg" because that is what the values are. (The picture below says "Group By" but it was automaticly set to "Avg". I just forgot to change it when i snipped for stack.

That results in:
[image: SumGroup]
[image: ChartSum]

But if i remove the "Total" function i get this:

[image: wosum]
[image: chartwosum]

So, removing the "Total" function works here...

Answer (score 0):

In your query, can you sort by ID, but not display it (e.g., in the query designer, sort 'descending/ascending' on the ID field, but clear the 'display' check box)?

As an aside, I've always had a tough time with Access charts... on my last project, the customer wanted a rather complex bar chart, and I ended-up drawing and resizing rectangle objects to get the look that the customer wanted.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The problem is i dont know how to sort by ID but use "Bin" a yaxis labels. (See table) It is already in the right order according to ID - It is access that resorts it because it is text and 50 is after 200.....

Comment: Yeah... I played around with it today. Even if you manually change the order of the chart's datasheet, it always re-sorts the data according to the y-axis; the chart sorts the data this way no matter what order that you provide the information. Like KevinDenen states, the charting tools in Access are sub-par.

Comment: What does sub-par mean?

Comment: Par means, 'average', or 'equivalent'. Subpar (I probably should not have hyphenated the word) means 'below par' or, 'below average'. I think that a lot of folks say that the Access chart functionality is subpar because in comparison to other Office products (Excel, Word), Access chart capabilities are not as intuitive, limited in options (such as colors), and generally display poorly. By the way, kudos for finding and posting answer below.